# Launching Lightning from command line?

Tags: command-line, thunderbird, lightning

Is there a command that allows me to launch Thunderbird's Lightning from command line? I want to add a command to the Thunderbird launcher that allows me to open to a Lightning page.

Comment: This lack of command-line to start lightning rise up a real integration problem. If I get an "invitation" (or a .ics file) by another way that mail client (Browser for instance), I can't tell "open with". I must save the file, open TB, go to the calendar and open the saved file. A really big regression ! As a consequence, in Ubuntu, the default calendar system is Evolution when the default mail system is Thunderbird. Rather incoherent ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way, at least not a known easy way, to start lightning directly from command line. There is a bug tracking here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359807

You can add yourself to the CC list (as what i did) to get updated about this feature request.

Sunbird is the standalone calendar, but it has been discontinued by Mozilla, so I cannot recommend it for you.

Comment: I figured it'd be worth a shot. Well, thanks anyways fossilet! :)